# Show drawer over bottom navigation bar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a drawer in a appbar and need to show it over the bottom navigation bar but can't put both in the same view, I don't know exactly how to do this.
[This is what it looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/op71S.png) and [this is what it needs to look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMbvJ.png)

This is part of the code of the view where the appbar is

```
class ContactsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final String token;
  final String qr;
  String code;
  final String name;

  ContactsPage({this.name, this.token, this.qr, this.code, Key key, this.title})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ContactsPageState createState() => _ContactsPageState();
}

class _ContactsPageState extends State<ContactsPage> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  List<Contact> contactList;
  bool showHorizontalBar = false;
  bool ready = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    var userService = new UserService();
    userService.getContacts(widget.token).then((value) => {
          print(value),
          if (value == '0')
            {
              Navigator.pushReplacement(
                  context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()))
            }
          else if (value == '3')
            {
              Navigator.pushReplacement(
                  context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()))
            }
          else
            {
              setState(() {
                contactList = value;
                ready = true;
              })
            },

          print(contactList),
        });
  }

  void showMessage(String message, [MaterialColor color = Colors.red]) {
    _scaffoldKey.currentState..removeCurrentSnackBar();
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(
        new SnackBar(backgroundColor: color, content: new Text(message)));
  }

  _navigateAndDisplaySelection(BuildContext context) async {
    final result = await Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => Scanner(
                qr: widget.qr,
                token: widget.token,
              )),
    );

    if (result != null) {
      showMessage('$result', Colors.red);
    }
  }

  Widget _addPerson() {
    return FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {
        _navigateAndDisplaySelection(context);
      },
      child: Icon(Icons.group_add),
      backgroundColor: Color(0xff83bb37),
    );
  }

  Widget buildMenuIcon() {
    return IconButton(
      icon: Icon(showHorizontalBar ? Icons.close : Icons.more_horiz),
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          showHorizontalBar = !showHorizontalBar;
        });
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _simplePopup() => PopupMenuButton<int>(
        itemBuilder: (context) => [
          PopupMenuItem(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.delete,
                    color: Color(0xff83bb37),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () => {},
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.favorite,
                    color: Color(0xff83bb37),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () => {},
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.mail,
                    color: Color(0xff83bb37),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () => {},
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.calendar_today,
                    color: Color(0xff83bb37),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () => {},
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.call,
                    color: Color(0xff83bb37),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () => {},
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.more_horiz,
          size: 20,
          color: Color(0xff4d4c48),
        ),
      );

  Widget _card(String first_name, String last_name, String email) {
    return Card(
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 5.0,
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(13.0),
              child: Image.asset(
                'assets/images/mujer.jpg',
                width: 60.0,
                height: 70.0,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            title: Row(
              children: [
                Text(
                  first_name,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Color(0xff4d4c48)),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 5.0),
                Text(
                  last_name,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Color(0xff4d4c48)),
                )
              ],
            ),
            subtitle: Container(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    email,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff4d4c48)),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 5.0,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Prowebglobal',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xff4d4c48), fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            trailing: _simplePopup(),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) =>
                          ContactDetails(token: widget.token, email: email)));
            },
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20.0,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget textContainer(String string, Color color) {
    return new Container(
      child: new Text(
        string,
        style: TextStyle(
            color: color, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, fontSize: 16.0),
        textAlign: TextAlign.start,
        maxLines: 2,
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
      ),
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
    );
  }

  Widget _titulo() {
    return new Container(
      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
      child: new Text(
        'Contactos',
        style: TextStyle(
            color: Color(0xff83bb37),
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 25.0),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      drawer: NavDrawer(
        token: widget.token,
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Color(0xfff0f0f0),
          title: Image.asset(
            'assets/images/logo-iso.png',
            height: 50.0,
            fit: BoxFit.contain,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
          ),
          iconTheme: new IconThemeData(color: Color(0xff707070)),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
              onPressed: () {
              },
            ),
          ]),
      body: Column(children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: 20.0,
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 2,
          child: _titulo(),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 20,
          child: Container(
            child: ready
                ? ListView(
                    children: contactList
                        .map(
                          (Contact contact) => _card("${contact.first_name}",
                              "${contact.last_name}", "${contact.email}"),
                        )
                        .toList())
                : Center(
                    child: Image.asset(
                      "assets/images/logo-gif.gif",
                      height: 125.0,
                      width: 125.0,
                    ),
                  ),
          ),
        ),
      ]),
      floatingActionButton: _addPerson(),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is where de bottom navigation menu is

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({
    this.token,
    this.code,
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String token;
  final String code;

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  String currentPage = 'contacts';

  changePage(String pageName) {
    setState(() {
      currentPage = pageName;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Map<String, Widget> pageView = <String, Widget>{
      "contacts": ContactsPage(
        code: widget.code,
        token: widget.token,
      ),
      "profile": ProfilePage(
        token: widget.token,
      ),
    };

    return Scaffold(
      body: pageView[currentPage],
      bottomNavigationBar: new BottomNavigationDot(
        paddingBottomCircle: 21,
        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        activeColor: Colors.black,
        items: [
          new BottomNavigationDotItem(
              icon: Icons.home,
              onTap: () {
                changePage("contacts");
              }),
          new BottomNavigationDotItem(icon: Icons.brush, onTap: () {}),
          new BottomNavigationDotItem(icon: Icons.notifications, onTap: () {}),
          new BottomNavigationDotItem(icon: Icons.favorite, onTap: () {}),
          new BottomNavigationDotItem(
              icon: Icons.person,
              onTap: () {
                changePage("profile");
              }),
        ],
        milliseconds: 400,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Edit:
I have thought on putting de appbar in the same level as de bottom navigation bar but I need to put different options on the appbar depending on the view so I thought on using diferent appbars, that's why I wanted it on the same level as the view.

Comment: Try putting the navbar at the root Scaffold

Comment: Scaffold(
body: pageView[currentPage],
drawer: Container(color: Colors.white,),
appBar: AppBar(),
bottomNavigationBar: new BottomNavigationDot(
.....

Comment: The exact scenario is not clear with the code you have provided so I'm assuming you have "PageView" as a parent in which u have the bottomNavigationBar and inside the childrens you have your "HomePage" with the appbar and drawer. So if u want to overlay the drawer on top of bottomNavigationBar you have to define it in same or higher lvl. So one way is to define the drawer in PageView but call it from your HomePage using Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(); and inside PageView ->   drawer: currentTabIndex == 0 ? NavigationDrawer() : null,

Comment: @kaxp Sorry for not putting all the code, I have edited it hoping it will be more clear. Thanks for the answer, I will try it.

Comment: @IsabelMorales are you able to solve it yet?